# Facebook Server Side Authentication- Session Variables not assigned values

Tags: php, facebook, session, authentication

I am unable to assign any value to SESSION variables in the Server Side Login Flow on facebook.. Can anyone tell me what the error is ??

I used to get the error that Headders have already been passed and session variables can not be set. So I set started output buffering at begining of the page and flush the buffer once the last session variable is assigned. The assignment dosen't seem to work since $_SESSION['state'] and $_SESSION['access_token'] have null values

```
   <?php ob_start(); session_start();
    $app_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $my_url = "http://mydomain.com".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    if(empty($code)) 
    {

    $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); // CSRF protection

    $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$app_id 
."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($my_url)."&state=".$_SESSION['state']."&scope=user_birthday,user_about_me,user_location,user_photos,friends_photos,email,user_website,friends_website,read_friendlists,publish_stream";

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
    ob_end_flush();

    }


   if ($_GET['state'] === $_SESSION['state']) //Ignoring CSRF protection for the moment 
//    since I am unable to assign SESSION variables any value, I actually have this as 
  //  if(200>150)/*
  {


    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"."client_id=".$app_id ."&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url). "&client_secret=".$app_secret."&code=".$code;

    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);

    $params = null;

    parse_str($response, $params);

    $_SESSION["access_ token"] = $params['access_token'];

    ob_end_flush(); // Session Varibale assigned, we can now flush output

    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$params['access_token'] ;

    $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url), true); 
    }


echo $params['access_token']."is the access token <BR> </BR>"; //this works fine, outputs Access token

echo $_SESSION['access_token']." is the access token" ; //Session Variables are not assigned value since $_SESSION['access_token'] is null

    ?>
```

Comment: For starters, why do you want to use output buffering to begin with?

Comment: Hi Tommy, Thanks for commenting. PHP sends out the headders if there are white spaces or lines in the code..These white spaces are identified as output even though PHP ignores them otherwise. Before any data can be output, headers need to set and  once the headers are sent, no further headers can be sent or Session Variables be set. - contd

Comment: contd : Output buffering collates all output in a memory buffer and sends out only headers to the client until ob_end_flush is encountered by the parser at which output stored in the buffer is released to the client. So, between ob_start and ob_end_flush, I can set headers and session variables between lines of output while avoiding an error on these lines - " Headers already sent, Unable to set session variable on line.. "

Comment: That is my raw and crude understanding of one of the uses(or misuses) of output buffering, please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Maybe we can do away with the badge "Tumbleweed"